# Can't get these to line up side by side

Tags: html, css

I can't get these to move to the center of the page. Anyone see what's wrong?

```
<ul id="contact">
<h1> Contact </h1>
    <p> Dreamstowheels@yahoo.com </p>
    <p> 2236 El Camino Real <br>
    Santa Clara Ca 95050 </p>
</ul>

<ul id="follow">
    <h1> Follow </h1>
    <img src="http://www.flagera.eu/sites/all/modules/socialmedia/icons/levelten/glossy/32x32/facebook.png">
</ul>

<ul id="supporters">
    <h1> Supporters </h1>
        <p><a href="http://www.cyclinginquisition.com/"    target="_blank">     Cyclinginquisition.com </a></p>
        <p><a href="http://www.colombiacyclingpro.com/" target="_blank"> Colombia Cycling Team </a></p>
        <p><a href="http://calmarcycles.com/" target="_blank"> Calmar Bicycles </a></p>
        <p><a href="https://www.facebook.com/rocksolidcycling" target="_blank"> Rock Solid Cycling </a></p>
        <p><a href="http://www.fastfreddieapparel.com/" target="_blank"> Fast Freddie Foundation </a></p>
        <p><a href="http://www.goldencreekservices.com/" target="_blank"> Golden Creek Services (Envio de Paquetes)  </a></p> 
</ul>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
footer{ /*Footer section attributes */
margin: -50px auto;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
/* border-top: solid 1px;*/
}
```

Let me know if you need to css for the contact, follow, and supporters divs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here ya go http://jsfiddle.net/u2Zb2/43/.... I looks centered in the fiddle but on the webpage it is just off to the left....

Comment: You can't center something that's `100%` wide. Mathematically speaking, the element would have to be less than `100%` wide to center it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u2Zb2/46/ - I think this one was you excepted

Answer (score 0):

Erase everything in your CSS code in fiddle and just put the following there.

```
footer{ margin:0 auto; text-align:center;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u2Zb2/45/

Comment: Yes so now everything is lining center on the page, now I want each div next to each other.... So, each div in line, but they line up in the center of the page no matter what size the browser

Comment: Well, its coded for a responsive website. Meaning, no matter what device looks at it, it will either be across or full screen.